# checkbox true on condition

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, schedulebatch

I have xyz object having date1__c (Date Data Type) field and active__c (Checkbox Data Type) field.
If date1__c = Today's date then checkbox should be checked otherwise it is unchecked.
How to achieve this functionality by customization.

Comment: use a formula field

Comment: I can not change the data type either can't create new field

Comment: So how can we achieve by customization?

Comment: then without code or VF you can't. code = batch to update daily and wfr to update if date field changes

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for code for this purpose. You need two workflow rules, or 1 Process Builder.

## Workflow Rule #1

Create a workflow with the criteria: Date1__c >= today.

Time-Delay field update "0 days after Date1__c": Active__c = true

Re-evaluate rules should be set to true.

## Workflow Rule #2

Create a workflow with the critera: Active__c = true.

Time-Delay field update: "1 day after Date1__c": Active__c = false

You will need to "touch" each record individually by data loader or some other tool once to queue all future interactions.

Process Builder would be designed in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple with Code and WFR

1. Create a WFR (inserted and every time it is edited) to set the checkbox based on the date field
2. Create a batch to run daily that simply queries all the xyz records and performs an update

Comment: Thank you Eric for your response.
As I am new to customization can you please share some code